# Compilar projeto com vários arquivos .c no VSCode - Linguagem C

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

Boa tarde, estou com problemas ao separar meu código em .c e .h no VSCode.

Segue a implementação:

**main.c**

```
#include "head.h"

int main(){
    printar(5);
}
```

**head.h**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void printar(int x);
```

**head.c**

```
#include "head.h"

void printar(int x){
    printf("\n%d", x);
}
```

Quando tento compilar no VSCode, recebo o seguinte erro:

> undefined reference to `printer`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como Compilar em C usando hearders customizados no VSCode?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438889/como-compilar-em-c-usando-hearders-customizados-no-vscode)

Comment: Infelizmente não, não sei como configurar esta parte.

Comment: O seu `main` tá sendo compilado em separado. Como fez para compilar ?

Comment: @Isac estou compilando usando uma extensão chamada C/C++, porém  parece que os arquivos head.c e head.h não estão sendo " linkados " sabe ? No Dev-C++ se eu fizer desta forma que fiz no VSCode, ele já consegue fazer o " linkamento "

Comment: @PierreCampos Mas você está a usar a extensão Code Runner para compilar e correr ? ou tá a fazer isso você pelo terminal ?

Comment: @Isac, estou compilando com o C/C++ Compile Run

Comment: Sinceramente não me parece que seja possível solucionar com essa extensão. Se você olhar para o [repositório dessa extensão no github](https://github.com/danielpinto8zz6/c-cpp-compile-run) vê o seguinte: "Compile & Run **single** c/c++ files"

Comment: Pois é, este foi meu receio, bom mas obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A extensão "C/C++ Compile Run" que está a usar só lhe permite compilar e executar um arquivo apenas, como é indicado no [próprio repositório](https://github.com/danielpinto8zz6/c-cpp-compile-run):

> Compile & Run **single** c/c++ files easly on vscode

E por isso com essa extensão não irá conseguir. No entanto pode utilizar a extensão [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) que já lhe irá permitir compilar com múltiplos ficheiros, assim como compilar para outras linguagens que não C ou C++.

Após ter instalado, aceda às configurações da extensão clicando na roda dentada da mesma e acedendo a *settings*.

No ecrã dos *settings* aceda à opção de edição do Executor Map, tal como vê na figura seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicione o seguinte bloco antes do `}` de fecho do arquivo:

```
,
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc *.c -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
}
```

O arquivo deverá ficar com um aspeto semelhante ao seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atente que deve existir uma virgula a separar a nova opção da ultima que já estava no arquivo.

Agora basta ir à seta para compilar e executar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A opção colocada no ficheiro faz compilar todos os .c que estão na pasta onde está a executar, e por isso pode alterar mais tarde essa instrução de compilação para outra, caso venha a ser necessário. Como a execução é pela pasta onde está, **tem de garantir que abriu no VSCode com "Open Folder" a pasta que tem os seus ficheiros .c** que vão ser compilados.

Também é util mencionar que a instrução adicionada é valida para compilação com gcc, e por isso terá que a ajustar se estiver a compilar com outros compiladores como o clang.

Adicionalmente a instrução também assume que o gcc está disponível em PATH, quer seja windows ou linux.

A instrução de compilação de múltiplos ficheiros com o gcc, o `*.c`, não é suportada em versões antigas do `gcc`, e por isso é recomendado que tenha uma versão minimamente atual do gcc (algo como versão 7 ou superior).

Comment: @PierreCampos Você tem que ter a pasta certa aberta no vscode. Primeiramente tem de fazer "Open folder" e abrir a pasta que tem os seus .h e .c

Comment: fiz isto, porém ocorre ainda o erro citado abaixo no meu repost

Comment: fiz como você me pediu, porém ainda tenho o mesmo erro, já tentei criar outra pasta também e adicionar os arquivos, porém não obtive exito, estou usando Windows, talvez haja algo que eu não tenha feito ?

Comment: @PierreCampos Na imagem que colocou na outra resposta dava para ver que não estava na pasta certa, pois ainda via a pasta testes na barra lateral esquerda. Se estiver na pasta correta verá os ficheiros fora de qualquer pasta, [assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f269G.png)

Comment: entendo, olhei naquela foto e realmente não estava, porém agora deixei como em sua imagem, seria  [assim][1]

Porém ainda obtenho o mesmo erro.


  [1]: https://i.imgur.com/caGzMcE.png

Comment: @PierreCampos Você continua a fazer qualquer coisa errado, em relação ao que eu disse. Veja o mesmo exemplo agora executado em Windows: [imagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrkGk.png). Apenas criei uma pasta, abri essa pasta no VSCode, criei os ficheiros com o código e executei direto, com os settings da resposta. Na imagem aparecem erros, porque não configurei o includePath no VSCode, mas isso não afeta o compilar e correr.

Comment: estranho, vou instalar novamente o VSCode e ver se dá certo

Comment: @PierreCampos Qual a versão do seu gcc ? abra a linha de comandos e execute `gcc --version`

Comment: gcc (tdm64-1) 4.9.2

Comment: @PierreCampos Isso é problema do gcc, eu aqui neste windows tou com o 7.2. Aconselho-te a reinstalar uma versão mais atual do gcc. Pelo pesquisei de forma rápida, o wildcard( o `*.c`) não é suportado em versões antigas do gcc.

Comment: UFA ! Deu certo agora, MUITO OBRIGADO !

Comment: @PierreCampos Sem problema, custou mas foi :)

Comment: salvou meu trabalho de Faculdade ! Compilar no Visual Code é mais bacana ;) Obrigado mesmo, um abraço.