# Compilar projeto com vários arquivos .cpp no VSCode - Linguagem C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Gostaria de compilar vários arquivos .cpp, usando também os .h, mas sem usar o cmd, direto no **VScode**, alguém sabe como faço?
Encontrei a respostas para .c em [Compilar projeto com vários arquivos .c no VSCode - Linguagem C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/438906/compilar-projeto-com-v%C3%A1rios-arquivos-c-no-vscode-linguagem-c), existem alguma alternativa semelhante para .cpp?

Comment: Você tentou ver a documentação? É bem completa. VS Code é orientado por uns arquivos .json que ficam na pasta .vscode. Se você entra em Terminal e Configure Tasks vai abrir a edição de tasks.json. Nele você pode criar uma tarefa, o task, e modificar a linha de comando que chama o compilador que está usando, para incluir todos os arquivos cpp ou c da pasta.

Comment: A opção é "args:" que são os parâmetros passados para compilar, e lá você pode criar uma lista ou colocar *.cpp ou qualquer expressão. E pode dar o nome que quiser ao task em si. E aí quanto usar a opção build control-shift-B ele vai aparecer na lista junto com os outros. Se você configurar como padrão pode usar só control-B e vai rodar direto esse

Comment: O que está dito na resposta linkada serve para o que precisa, apenas tem de trocar `gcc` por `g++` e `*.c` por `*.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

Para compilar vários arquivos no CodeBlock (talvez seja igual no VSCode) precisa criar um projeto e incluir no projeto todos os arquivos que você quer compilar, inclusive os arquivos de biblioteca.
Importante: em cada projeto, pode ter apenas um arquivo que tenha a função main().
No Visual Studio também utiliza a regra acima.
Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).